# Maven-Android-Plugin 3.8.2 causes ActionBarSherlock issues

Tags: android, maven, actionbarsherlock, android-maven-plugin

I've been a happy ABS user for a number of years now but since my last updated to the [maven-android-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) I cannot get the built app to run on devices without a native Action Bar...i.e. anything before Honeycomb.

The exception I am getting is;

```
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't find content container view
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:1015)
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:902)
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:836)
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:261)
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at com.oceanlife.core.activity.AbstractThemedActionBarActivity.onCreate(AbstractThemedActionBarActivity.java:32)
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at com.oceanlife.activity.SpotListingActivity.onCreate(SpotListingActivity.java:119)
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
01-11 15:47:04.413: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     ... 11 more
```

I am suspecting that my upgrade to the android-maven-plugin v3.8.2 alongside the required upgrade to Maven 3.1.1 has caused this problem (and not ABS itself) ...so my question is, how can I diagnose what is wrong? Interestingly when debug the portion of code causing the problem `ActionBarSherlockCompat#generateLayout` the layout is found correctly but the underlying id is not, review the comments inline below;

```
if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "[generateLayout] using screen XML " + mActivity.getResources().getString(layoutResource));
  View in = mActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResource, null);
  mDecor.addView(in, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT));

  // mDecor not null and the orginal resource contains an id called "abs__content"
  ViewGroup contentParent = (ViewGroup)mDecor.findViewById(R.id.abs__content);
  if (contentParent == null) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't find content container view");
  }
```

The only thing abnormal about the child view with this id is that it has the following namespace;

```
com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout
```

Any assistance with getting my build back working on Gingerbread devices most appreciated. And to the SDK 14+ armada, this is my last release to Gingerbread. Thank you in advance.

---

**Update:** I have confirmed that this is a direct effect of upgrading to the *maven-android-plugin* at v3.8.2 (and the consequential 3.1.1 Maven upgrade).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the apklib of ActionBarSherlock with 3.8.1 and the aar with 3.8.2. We are currently trying to get support for both working nicely in our works towards 3.8.3...

Comment: Thanks Manfred. I'll return to this when v3.8.3 is released and provide an update. In the interim, I have downgraded ...no biggy for me as the 3.8.1 release was all good for me.